# Go HTTP memory use per persistent connection

Tags: http, memory, go, profile

I'm writing a Go web server that sends [Server-Sent Events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) to a load of clients. I'd like it to support tens of thousands of simultaneous connections. Here is my code (it just keeps the connection open and sends keep-alive events):

```
func handleTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    h := w.Header()
    h.Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream; charset=utf-8")
    h.Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
    h.Set("Connection", "keep-alive")

    flusher := w.(http.Flusher)
    notifier := w.(http.CloseNotifier)

    flusher.Flush()

    // Just send keep-alives.
    keepAliveTime := 5 * time.Second
    keepAlive := time.NewTimer(keepAliveTime)
    defer keepAlive.Stop()

    for {
        select {
        case <-notifier.CloseNotify():
            // The connection has been closed.
            return

        case <-keepAlive.C:
            if _, err := io.WriteString(w, "event: keep-alive\ndata: null\n\n"); err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                return
            }
            flusher.Flush()
            keepAlive.Reset(keepAliveTime)
        }
    }
}
```

With 1000 connections Windows reports about 70 kB of RAM use per connection. If I add in all the stuff I am actually doing (there's another goroutine, and some minor event encoding functions) it balloons to 300 kB per connection. This seems like lots. With 1000 connections here is what `pprof heap` says:

```
14683.25kB of 14683.25kB total (  100%)
Dropped 12 nodes (cum <= 73.42kB)
Showing top 10 nodes out of 23 (cum >= 512.19kB)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
11091.50kB 75.54% 75.54% 11091.50kB 75.54%  io.copyBuffer
    2053kB 13.98% 89.52%     2053kB 13.98%  net/http.newBufioWriterSize
     514kB  3.50% 93.02%      514kB  3.50%  net/http.newBufioReader
  512.56kB  3.49% 96.51%   512.56kB  3.49%  runtime.makeslice
  512.19kB  3.49%   100%   512.19kB  3.49%  net.newFD
         0     0%   100% 11091.50kB 75.54%  io.Copy
         0     0%   100%  1540.19kB 10.49%  main.main
         0     0%   100%   512.19kB  3.49%  net.(*TCPListener).AcceptTCP
         0     0%   100%   512.19kB  3.49%  net.(*netFD).accept
         0     0%   100%   512.19kB  3.49%  net.(*netFD).acceptOne
```

So I have a few questions:

1. Why is the memory use so seemingly high. I would have expected something like 10 kB per connection.
2. Why does pprof think the heap is 14 MB, but Windows says the memory use is 70 MB? Is the rest the stack?
3. Is there any way I can transfer control of the HTTP response to a central goroutine, and return from `handleTest()` without closing the connection? Would that save me memory or is the memory use all in the `http.ResponseWriter` object?

**Edit**: For 3. it looks like I can use [Hijacker](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Hijacker)

**Edit 2**: I tried reimplementing it using `Hijacker`. It reduced memory usage to about 10 kB per connection, which is much more reasonable!

Comment: For 2: In addition to heap there is stack, heap bitmap for GC, free space for allocations (roughly the same size as heap). Also memory is not returned to OS immediately.

Comment: Have you run some serious load tests? The base memory consumption may distort your results. I'd go for increasing the number of concurrent connections to say 50% of the expected load (might need to have a grid of clients to generate the load) and have a look how the memory consumption is then. A side node: even with 14MB per 1k connections, given todays RAM sizes, I would not put too much effort in premature optimization here. 70k+ connections/GB seem to be a good deal to me. Just make sure that you can scale horizontally, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Yeah I've gone up to 10k connections. The base consumption is only 3 MB so shouldn't affect it too much. And pprof is wrong - it is never 14 MB per 1k connections.

Comment: What windows reports used and what your program is using can be wildly different. The OS can allocate memory however it deems most efficient, and often won't free that memory unless there pressure to do so. Taking the total windows memory usage and dividing it up doesn't really tell you what the server is actually doing per connection.

Comment: The "private working set" is specifically memory that can't be used by other applications it isn't caches or unused virtual memory or anything. It's possible that *Go* is allocating more than it needs, but I don't believe that to be the case because the memory usage is proportional to the number of connections - it doesn't increase in steps as you might expect. Anyway, the point is that the Windows value is more relevant than Go's self-reporting in this case.

Comment: You can check the actual memory stats to alleviate any uncertainty - total consumption from the program's perspective will be `Sys - HeapReleased` (stacks can't be freed). On top of the multiple buffers that will be allocated for an http request, there will be at least 6K of stack used by the 3 goroutines for your handler.  Running the program with gctrace will better show you how the memory is being used on a whole, since peak consumption is tied to GC behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does pprof think the heap is 14 MB, but Windows says the memory use is 70 MB? Is the rest the stack?

Besides the heap, there's also the Go runtime, the stack, the code segment. Also the OS might allocate more than it's actually needed. Also, is the amount reported by Windows the resident memory or the total allocated by the OS memory?

Comment: It says "Private working set" so I assume that is resident. Also I don't think it is because of over-allocation as I gradually add connections and the memory use goes up very linearly - not in steps. The base memory use is only 3MB so I don't think the Go runtime or code use much.